# Splitting an Amount over X days

Tags: php

I have a small script that splits out an amount of revenue over a span of days. I can't seem to wrap my head around allowing for any number of days. Currently I can only get it to work if I hard-set an array of %s for each amount of days, which obviously isn't going to work for large sets of day combinations.

If anyone has an idea as to how to accomplish this, I'd be ever grateful.

My Code:

```
<?php
//define variables
$ammount = 11320.00;
$start_date = "12/30/2011";
$days = 5;

//setup array of percents
$percent_array = array(3=>array(0 => 45, 1 => 30, 2 => 25), 4=>array(0 => 40, 1 => 30, 2 => 20, 3 => 10),4=>array(0 => 35, 1 => 25, 2 => 20, 3 => 10, 4 => 10));

//handle formatting the date for use in loop
$format = 'D m/d/Y';
$sDate = strtotime($start_date);

if ($usersTS !== false) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
        echo date($format, strtotime('+' . $i . ' day', $sDate));
        echo " : ";
        echo number_format($ammount * ($percent_array[$days][$i] / 100), 2, ".", ",");
        echo "<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "No valid date supplied";
};
?>
```

Output:

```
Fri 12/30/2011 : 3,962.00
Sat 12/31/2011 : 2,830.00
Sun 01/01/2012 : 2,264.00
Mon 01/02/2012 : 1,132.00
Tue 01/03/2012 : 1,132.00
```

Comment: fyi, amount only has 1 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to distribute the amount over X number of days such that the earlier days are higher weighted?

Sounds like you just need to find the right function. You can try [`y=1/(x+1)`](http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/graphs/equations/basic.jsp#v1=y=1/%28x+1%29&v2=0&v3=10&v4=0&v5=1) for example. Then solve for `x` number of days, and use each day as a percent sum of the `y` values.

Answer (score 1):

well, I'm not quite sure by what amount you want to split for each day, but I think you are over thinking this problem?  Couldn't you just divide the amount by the days?  Or am I missing something...  If you could post more info about your objective that would be helpful :)

Comment: that's what I was thinking too... although by reading his code, it doesn't look like he wants to split the amounts evenly.. i'm not sure what algorithm he's using

Comment: @Mark, I think he has different percentages to split by on each day... which definitely complicates things...

Comment: Indeed - I need to make the first few days heavy no matter how many days there are, and then distribute the remaining amount over the rest of the project.

Comment: @Zephaera, are you going to share those ratios?  I think the issue here is that you are not precisely clear on what you are trying to accomplish.  If you know exactly "what" you want to accomplish we can help you with the "how" part...

Comment: @Zephaera do you have any requirements for how much needs to be paid in the first few days? eg: 50% over the first 2 days and then the remaining 50% over the remaining days?

Comment: I see the disconnect in my question, but I don't have a very good way to explain it. I'll work on it a bit today and see if I can revise. Thanks for all your thoughts.